# If A is the 4 by 4 matrix of ones, find the eigenvalues and the determinant of A−I

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I want to find the eigen values and eigen vectors of a matrix with all 1's

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}

Only 1 independent would be left,

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
Now, Let's assume λ= 1.

A-λI would give me,

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}
With eigen values as, -1,-1,-1 and 3.

Ultimately, λ1=3 and λ2=-1.

But this is something I have assumed, how can I get eigen values and its vectors by a method? Or what steps should I take ahead? Thanks in advance

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of the matrix with all ones is $\lambda^4-4\lambda^3$.

Comment: Okay. Implies, λ=4

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$ is also an eigenvector, but not with eigenvalue $4$.

Comment: I'm not getting these values. How? @robjohn

Comment: In the columns of $s$ are the eigenvectors and in the diagonal of $j$ the eigenvalues https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecoposition+%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D

Comment: Looks understanding to me. But I'm not allowed to use that @janmarqz

Comment: combine what robjohn is saying and from what automatic calculation can do for you to understand better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

To begin with, obtain the characteristic polynomial:

\begin{align*}
\det(A - \lambda I) & =
\begin{vmatrix}
1 - \lambda & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 - \lambda & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 - \lambda & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 - \lambda  
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
& =
\begin{vmatrix}
4 - \lambda & 1 & 1 & 1\\
4 - \lambda & 1 - \lambda & 1 & 1\\
4 - \lambda & 1 & 1 - \lambda & 1\\
4 - \lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 - \lambda  
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
& =
(4-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 - \lambda & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 - \lambda & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 - \lambda  
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
& = 
(4-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -\lambda & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & -\lambda & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & - \lambda  
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
& = (\lambda - 4)\lambda^{3}
\end{align*}

whence we get the eigenvalues $\lambda\in\{0,4\}$.

Can you take it from here?